# about combination of rectifiable curves

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, curves

Suppose $a$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$, there exists points $a = t_{0} < t_{1} <\cdots<t_{n-1} <t_{n} =b$, and $\gamma\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is continuous. Then, are the following equivalent, or is there any counterexample?

(1) $\gamma$ is rectifiable.

(2) For all $1\leq i\leq n$, the restriction $\gamma|_{[t_{i-1}, t_{i}]}$ is rectifiable.

If this is true, then $$\sum_{i}\mbox{the length of }\gamma|_{[t_{i-1}, t_{i}]} = \mbox{the length of }\gamma$$ ?

I proved (1)→(2), but couldn’t prove (2)→(1), for partitions of gamma have to be chosen compatibly with each partitions of the restrictions of gamma.

The definition of “rectifiable” and “length”:

Let $\gamma\colon[a, b]\to\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be continuous.

(1) For each partition $P = \{a = x_{0} < x_{1} <\cdots<x_{n-1} <x_{n} =b\}$, define $\Lambda(P, \gamma) =  \sum_{i}\|\gamma(x_{i}) - \gamma(x_{i-1})\|$.

(2) $\gamma$ is called rectifiable if $\sup_{P} \Lambda(P, \gamma) < +\infty$.

(3) If $\gamma$ is rectifiable, its length is defined as the supremum.

Comment: What is your question about this exercise? What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: I proved (1)→(2), but couldn’t prove (2)→(1), for partitions of gamma have to be chosen compatibly with each partitions of the restrictions of gamma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (2).

For $a\le a'<b'\le b$ and a partition $Q=\{x_0,...,x_m\}$ of $[a',b']$ with $a'=x_0<...<x_m=b' $ let $G(Q)=\sum_{j=1}^m\|\gamma (x_{j-1})-\gamma (x_j)\|.$ By the Triangle Inequality, if $Q$ and $Q'$ are partitions of $[a',b']$ with $Q\subseteq Q'$ then $G(Q)\le G(Q').$

For $1\le i\le n$ let $L_i$ be the length of $\gamma|_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}\,.$

For any partition $P$ of $[a,b],$ consider the partition $P'=P\cup \{t_0,..,t_n\}.$ For $1\le i\le  n,$ observe that $P'_i= P'\cap [t_{i-1},t_i]$ is a partition of $[t_{i-1},t_i],$ so $G(P'_i)\le L_i.$

Also observe that $G(P')=\sum_{i=1}^nG(P'_i).$

Since $P\subseteq P'$ we have $G(P)\le G(P')=\sum_{i=1}^nG(P'_i)\le \sum_{i=1}^nL_i.$